# Change the shape of default tile in windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8, tile

In windows 8 when we build our application and check it in simulator then tiles are created in default shape of square , I want to have a rectangle tile for my application like the "video" tile on the start page . Is there a way i can manage this

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It just takes a few steps to do this:

1. Add a 310x150 pixel image to your project
2. Open your app's "Package.appxmanifest"
3. In the "Tile" section, set the "Wide logo" to point that image

The app will then use the wide tile by default when first installed, but keep in mind that the user can ultimately decide whether the wide or square tile is shown.  (You can't control the choice programmatically - except I suppose by not offering a wide tile at all.)

For more, see:

- [Quickstart: Creating a default tile using the Microsoft Visual Studio manifest editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465437.aspx)
- [Choosing your app images](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh846296.aspx)
- [DefaultTile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211427.aspx)